# What are the '_modname' built-in modules in Python? What are they used for?

Tags: python, module

I might be missing something from the documentation but I can't see to find it and googling is not a trivial tast with this.

I noticed when looking at the `importlib` module that it used an `import _imp` statement to import `_imp` for some additional functionality. Apparently, Python is packed with these `_<modname>` modules that are importable and (without testing) usable.

Using `ipython` a list of the underscore modules reveals that there's plenty of them:

```
In [2]: import _
__future__           _elementtree         _sha512
_ast                 _functools           _signal
_bisect              _hashlib             _sitebuiltins
_bootlocale          _heapq               _socket
_bz2                 _imp                 _sqlite3
```

And the list continues. The modules are of course importable and apparently functional:

```
In [2]: import _imp

In [3]: _imp
Out[3]: <module '_imp' (built-in)>
```

Considering `PEP 8` I would assume they are internal *private* details for a given module, is this assumption correct? If not, what are they used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_` prefix typically indicates the module is written in C, and is generally used via a pure-Python wrapper rather than used directly. For example, the `socket` module starts out

```
import _socket
from _socket import *
```

meaning `socket` is making available items exported by `_socket`.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot that in the source the `c` filename is often different than that exposed at the end and importable in Python. So `_imp` is actually `import.c`. Thanks.